# Is there any way to show screenshot of url ie website in listview android

Tags: java, android

I want to show only the screenshots of list of websites using url. The screenshot has to be loaded in listview of android. I want to show preview of the website before loading the webview. I request help in resolving the issue in loading web screenshot of URL before loading the website in android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking how to render the contents of a webview as an image? In that case you would have to render the webview first; the picture can't be displayed before the webview content is loaded (because what would the snapshot be of?)

Something like this might be a start:

```
webView.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap img = webView.getDrawingCache();
imageView.setImageBitmap(img);
```